# Detrmining Hold-In current

Tags: relay, control

A 120V control relay has an inrush of 400VA, and a hold-in rating of 100VA.

How do I determine the hold in current, MATHAMATICALLY, WHAT'S THE FORMULA?

Comment: Do you understand that VA is Volts times Amps?

Comment: MATHAMATICALLY, there is no formula.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically,The formula is:
$$ I = \frac{VA}{V}\text, $$

Which, in your case, is:

$$ I = \frac{100 \require{cancel}\cancel{V}A}{120\require{cancel} \cancel{V}} = 0.833\text { amperes} $$